# Netbeans suddenly creating files and writing log output to c:\windows directory

Tags: java, netbeans

I installed a new hard drive with JDK 1.6.0_20 and Netbeans 6.9.1. I copied an existing Netbeans project from the old drive and imported it into NB 6.9.1.

Now it is suddenly creating output files and writing Log4J .log files in the c:\windows directory instead of the project directory.

I created the test class below outside of NB to see what is happening. Running this outside of NB gives the expected results. Importing this class into a new NB project also gives the expected results. But if I copy this class into the other project then it gives c:\windows for all 3 outputs.

What could be the problem with this one project that causes it to act like it's project directory is c:\windows?

```
public class DirectoryTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println(userDir);
        File file = new File(".");

        try {
            System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Add 4 spaces before your code so it can be formatted correctly please

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: I just updated to NetBeans 6.9.1 and I'm not sure what "imported" means in this context.

Comment: What does your Log4j configuration look like?

Comment: I should have said that I opened the project with NB 6.9.1 instead of saying that I imported the project.  Import is an Eclipse concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try deleting the `nbproject` & `build` folders and re-creating it as a "Project with Existing Sources".

As a last resort, delete the NetBeans cache folder from wherever it is stored on your platform, typically in a hidden folder of your home directory.

Comment: That was the solution.  I deleted all the nb* directories and the various build*.xml and nbbuild*.xml files and recreated it as you said.  That project has seen several versions of NB, so it may have gotten confused.

Answer (score 0):

Check the setting "Working directory" in the "Run" section of the project properties. Simply set your project's directory there.

Comment: That had no effect.  Log4j is still writing to c:\windows and the test program above still shows c:\windows for all three outputs.

Comment: Do you have multiple "Run" definitions? The output for log4j could be defined through a log4j.xml (or .properties) that's somewhere on your classpath. If you are 100% the run configuration that you are using has the correct directory defined, then I don't know what could be wrong there