# Error When Creating JFrame -> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code

Tags: java, swing, jframe, netbeans-8

So, this is the complete error I get:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: (java.lang.Object)boolean
    at GUI.NewJFrame.main (NewJFrame.java:57)
C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

So, since I've **just created the project and then created the JFrame**, I don't think the code will help because I didn't even change anything in it. 
But I'll post it anyways.

*NewJFrame*:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package GUI;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I can't compile my code because of this error.
I've just changed the OS to Windows 10, I could create a JFrame normally on Windows 8.1.

Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: check your JDK version, I want to know it - run `javac -version`, `java -version` and pass me outputs

Comment: In my editor (probably wrong):
`}`
`}` **THIS**
`} catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Line numbers in example match exception, unlike most posts

Comment: `for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }`
This is the line 56 - 60 (if line is the 57)



@JakubKaszycki these are the outputs from the cmd commands:

http://prntscr.com/9tgen5

Comment: If you can't open the print screen, shortly:
-javac version returned command not recognized 
-java version returned 1.8.0_66 with 'Java SE Runtime Enviroment = Build 1.8.0_66-b17' and 'Java HotSpot 64 Bit Server VM build "25.66-b17", mixed mode'

Comment: Code runs fine; some other things to try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3538866/230513).

Comment: Unfortunately, although I've tried all they said in the post @trashgod mentioned, nothing worked. I'll try reinstalling NetBeans.

Comment: Seems to work okay for me. Have you tried a clean and build?  Have you tried removing the local cache? Have you tried creating a new project and copying the to it?

Comment: So, I've tried reinstalling NetBeans and it worked. I don't know what was the issue, but reinstalling fixed it. 

Thanks for everyone that tried helping me!!

Comment: Probably Java SDK was not installed properly, as your `javac -version` returned some error.

Comment: Voting to close as Cannot Reproduce after re-install. Thanks for letting us know :P